# SQL Server - Delete (x) number of rows depending on a WHERE caluse

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where throughout the day, records are set to delete (BOOLEAN VALUE), but are not actually deleted. A list of these values is displayed within a view (let's call it `ViewToDelete`), for example:

```
ID      DELETE
--------------
1         1
4         1
5         1
```

At the end of the day I want to be able to delete these values present in this view all in one go, can this be achieved and if so how?

```
DELETE FROM mytablename 
WHERE ID = ViewToDelete.ID 

--THIS WOULD WORK IF THERE WAS 1 VALUE, BUT FOR MULTIPLE VALUES
--IT RETURNS AN ERROR AS I WOULD EXPECT
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by `JOIN`ing to the view:

```
Delete  M
From    MyTableName     M
Join    ViewToDelete    V   On  V.Id = M.Id
                            And V.Delete = 1
```

Comment: well, you also need to add the `DELETE = 1` there

Comment: @Lamak Good catch - added.

Comment: works a treat and luckily it was on a test table as it deleted everything haha ;) for the 2 years Ive done SQL I have never had to do something like this, I knew it would be simple! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write

```
Delete from Viewtodelete where delete=1
```

If the view fetches all its data from only 1 table.